# What's the most efficient way to get all attachments from any row in every sheet using Smartsheet API?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

Bottom line, is there any way to get a list of attachments without drilling down to the row level having to make 2 calls to get the `attachment id` and then 1 more call to get the attachment?

I'm trying to write a script that uses Smartsheet's API to get all desired attachments from all/specific sheets. So far I have code that accomplishes the goal but it's super inefficient because it has to go through thousands of rows checking to see if there's an attachment or not. Both lines of code return objects or list of objects containing "Attachments" property, but it's always null.

```
// get all sheet resources
PaginatedResult<Sheet> sheets = smartsheet.SheetResources.ListSheets(null, null, null);

var includeAttachments = new List<SheetLevelInclusion> { SheetLevelInclusion.ATTACHMENTS };
var sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, includeAttachments, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Each method has a `IEnumerable<SheetLevelInclusion>` parameter but I'm not completely sure how to leverage it if it's even possible.

I'll provide my entire method to give you more context. I've also included a `FilterSheets` method that I have yet to implement. I'm also open to `Python` answers.

```
private List<SMTPAttachment> GetAttachments(SmartsheetClient smartsheet)
{
  var includeAttachments = new List<SheetLevelInclusion> { SheetLevelInclusion.ATTACHMENTS };

  // get all sheet resources
  PaginatedResult<Sheet> sheets = smartsheet.SheetResources.ListSheets(null, null, null);

  // filter out sheets that don't have desired attachments
  var filteredSheets = FilterSheets(sheets);

  // initalize necessary objects to store data
  var attachments = new List<SMTPAttachment>();

  // for each sheet in sheets:
  foreach (var tempSheet in filteredSheets)
  {
    var sheetId = (long)tempSheet.Id;
    var sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, includeAttachments, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    // for each row in sheet.Rows
    foreach (Row row in sheet.Rows)
    {
      long rowId = (long)row.Id;
      var paging = new PaginationParameters(true, 1, 1);
      var smtpAttachment = new SMTPAttachment();

      PaginatedResult<Attachment> updatedAttachment = smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AttachmentResources.ListAttachments(
        sheetId,
        rowId,
        paging
      );
      if (updatedAttachment.Data.Count != 0)
      {
        var attachmentInfo = updatedAttachment.Data.FirstOrDefault();
        if (attachmentInfo != null)
        {
          // finally getting the attachment here
          var attachment = smartsheet.SheetResources.AttachmentResources.GetAttachment(sheetId, (long)attachmentInfo.Id);
          smtpAttachment.Attachment = attachment;
          smtpAttachment.Name = attachment.Name;
          smtpAttachment.Url = attachment.Url;
          smtpAttachment.MimeType = attachment.MimeType;
          attachments.Add(smtpAttachment);
          Console.WriteLine("Attaching file : " + attachment.Name);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("No Data for row: " + rowId);
      }
    }
  }

  return attachments;
}

private List<Sheet> FilterSheets(PaginatedResult<Sheet> sheets)
{
  /// TODO: implement filter code
  var filteredSheets = sheets.Data.ToList().Where(sheet => sheet.Id == sheet.Id).ToList();  

  return filteredSheets;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE:***

My original answer (below) assumes that you're wanting other sheet-related data in addition to information about the attachments. If that IS your scenario, then using a single **[Get Sheet](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/sheets#operation/getSheet)** API request is the most efficient way of doing that, as it'll allow you to use a single API call to retrieve all sheet-related data AND data about attachments within the sheet.

However, if you're *only wanting data about attachments* within the specified sheet, you might consider instead using the **[List Attachment](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/attachments#operation/attachments-listOnSheet)** operation. This operation returns information about all attachments that exist within the sheet, regardless of location (i.e., sheet attachments, row attachments, discussion attachments at the sheet level, discussion attachments at the row level). Using the **List Attachment** operation (if you're only wanting attachment-related data and don't need any other sheet data) is more efficient than using the **Get Sheet** operation to retrieve attachment data, as the response will be much smaller and the code you need to write to process the response much simpler. Here's some sample code:

```
SmartsheetClient smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder()
    .SetAccessToken("ADD_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE")
    .Build();

var sheetId = (long) 3932034054809476;

// Omit pagination parameters
PaginatedResult<Attachment> attachments = smartsheet.SheetResources.AttachmentResources.ListAttachments(sheetId, null);

Console.WriteLine("Number of attachments found = " + attachments.TotalCount);

foreach(var attachment in attachments.Data) {
    Console.WriteLine("Attachment name | ID | location: " + attachment.Name + " | " + attachment.Id + " | " + attachment.ParentType);
}
```

When run against the sheet I've described in the original answer (below), this code produces the following console output:

[image: console output from List Attachments operation]

Please note that regardless of which API method you use to retrieve attachment info (**Get Sheet** or **List Attachments**), the API response will only contain a subset of metadata for each attachment. For each attachment in a **Get Sheet** or **List Attachments** response, you'll need to issue a **[Get Attachment](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/attachments#operation/attachments-get)** request to retrieve the full set of metadata about the attachment -- including the `url` property that you can use to access the file itself.

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

It's possible to get info about all attachments contained within a sheet by issuing a single **Get Sheet** request (with the appropriate `SheetLevelInclusion` values specified) -- but you'll need to evaluate 4 separate parts of the response to identify all attachments in the sheet. This is because there are 4 different places where an attachment can be added:

1. at the SHEET level
2. within a DISCUSSION at the SHEET level
3. at the ROW level
4. within a DISCUSSION at the ROW level

For example, consider a sheet in Smartsheet that contains the 6 attachments listed in the following Smartsheet screenshot, where:

- `file6.txt` is attached to a DISCUSSION at the SHEET level
- `file5.txt` is attached at the SHEET level
- `file4.txt` is attached to a DISCUSSION at the ROW level (on row #1)
- `file3.txt` and `file2.txt` are attached at the ROW level (on row #4)
- `file1.txt` is attached at the ROW level (on row #1)

[image: smartsheet attachments pane]

The JSON response to a **Get Sheet** request for this sheet would look like the following (*edited for brevity, to only show relevant data within the response*):

```
{
    "id": 3932034054809476,
    ...
    "columns": [
        ...
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 6933706290423684,
            "rowNumber": 1,
            ...
            "discussions": [
                {
                    "id": 5173128113219460,
                    "title": "This is a discussion!",
                    "commentCount": 1,
                    "commentAttachments": [
                        {
                            "id": 1958653853755268,
                            "name": "file4.txt",
                            "attachmentType": "FILE",
                            ...
                        }
                    ],
                    ...
                }
            ],
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": 1061849918400388,
                    "name": "file1.txt",
                    "attachmentType": "FILE",
                    ...
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1304206756210564,
            "rowNumber": 2,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 770536852088708,
            "rowNumber": 3,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 7046650170566532,
            "rowNumber": 4,
            ...
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": 7092080722634628,
                    "name": "file3.txt",
                    "attachmentType": "FILE",
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "id": 2426000334972804,
                    "name": "file2.txt",
                    "attachmentType": "FILE",
                    ...
            ]
        }
    ],
    "discussions": [
        {
            "id": 4967439377950596,
            "title": "This is a comment on the sheet level.",
            "commentCount": 1,
            "commentAttachments": [
                {
                    "id": 976830369687428,
                    "name": "file6.txt",
                    "attachmentType": "FILE",
                    ...
                }
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": 135383999375236,
            "name": "file5.txt",
            "attachmentType": "FILE",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

This JSON response shows the attachments present at the various locations described previously.

The following C# code issues a **Get Sheet** request (with the appropriate `SheetLevelInclusion` values specified) to retrieve the specified sheet (including info about all attachments present at any location within the sheet). It then looks in each of the 4 locations and writes output to the console when it finds an attachment.

```
SmartsheetClient smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder()
    .SetAccessToken("ADD_YOUR_TOKEN_STRING_HERE")
    .Build();

var sheetId = (long) 3932034054809476;

// Sheet inclusions must specify attachments AND discussions in order to get all attachments present within the sheet
// (i.e., attachments present on: SHEET object, ROW objects, DISCUSSION objects at the SHEET level, DISCUSSION objects at the ROW LEVEL)
var sheetLevelInclusion = new List<SheetLevelInclusion> { SheetLevelInclusion.ATTACHMENTS, SheetLevelInclusion.DISCUSSIONS };

Console.WriteLine("Loading sheet id: " + sheetId);

// Get the sheet.
var sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, sheetLevelInclusion, null, null, null, null, null, null);

Console.WriteLine("Loaded " + sheet.Rows.Count + " rows from sheet: " + sheet.Name);
Console.WriteLine("---------");

// 1- Attachments that exist on the SHEET object
if (sheet.Attachments != null) {
    // iterate through all attachments found on SHEET object
    foreach (var attachment in sheet.Attachments) {
        Console.WriteLine("Attachment found (at SHEET-level): " + attachment.Name + " (attachment ID = " + attachment.Id + ")");
        
        // Add logic to process attachment here. 
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("---------");

// 2- Attachments that exist on the DISCUSSION objects at the SHEET level
if (sheet.Discussions != null) {
    // iterate through all discussion objects (at the sheet level), looking for attachments on each discussion.
    foreach (var discussion in sheet.Discussions) {
        if (discussion.CommentAttachments != null) {

            foreach (var attachment in discussion.CommentAttachments) {
                Console.WriteLine("Attachment found (on SHEET-level Discussion): " + attachment.Name + " (attachment ID = " + attachment.Id + ")");

                // Add logic to process attachment here. 
            }

        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("---------");

// 3- Attachments that exist on ROW objects
foreach (var row in sheet.Rows) {
    
    if (row.Attachments != null) {
        // process attachments on the current row
        foreach (var attachment in row.Attachments) {
            Console.WriteLine("Attachment found (at ROW-level) on Row # " + row.RowNumber + ": " + attachment.Name + " (attachment ID = " + attachment.Id + ")");

            // Add logic to process attachment here. 
        }
    }

    // 4- Attachments that exist on DISCUSSION objects at the ROW level
    if (row.Discussions != null) {

        // iterate through all discussion objects (on the current row), looking for attachments on each discussion.
        foreach (var discussion in row.Discussions) {
            if (discussion.CommentAttachments != null) {

                foreach (var attachment in discussion.CommentAttachments) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Attachment found (on ROW-level Discussion) in Row # " + row.RowNumber + ": " + attachment.Name + " (attachment ID = " + attachment.Id + ")");

                    // Add logic to process attachment here. 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("---------");
```

When run against the sheet I've described previously, this code produces the following console output:

[image: console output]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly how I would want/expect my code to run, but the attachment property on my sheet object still is showing up as null. Could it be some sheet configuration that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The **sheet.Attachments** collection will only be non-null if there have been attachments added at the SHEET level (which isn’t very common). The most common scenario is for attachments to be added at the ROW level. To get those attachments you’ll need to evaluate the row.Attachments property for each row. For good measure, I recommend evaluating all 4 locations where attachments can exist — as I’ve shown in the example code posted.

Comment: Okay, so I realized that my row.Attachment is there, however, I don't have access to it's URL property until I utilize the smartsheet.SheetResources..AttachmentResources.GetAttchament method

Comment: I've added an update at the start of my answer, and have addressed your latest comment there. If this answer sufficiently addresses your original question (post), please mark it as **accepted** so that others are more likely to benefit from this info in the future. Thanks!

Comment: using AttachmentResources.ListAttachments does speed up my process so I will accept this as an answer. but why does AttachmentResources.ListAttachments not provide URL? I still have to get the attachment Id to call AttachmentResources.GettAttachment just to get the URL

Comment: I suspect that *not* including the `Attachment.url` property was an API design decision made in an effort to minimize the size of API responses (thereby improving performance of the API). That said, seems like making the API response slightly larger (by including the `url` property) is a worthwhile tradeoff considering the benefit of not having to make an additional `Get Attachment` API call for every attachment. I've submitted a [feature request](https://help.smartsheet.com/contact/smartsheetapp) to Smartsheet asking for the `Attachment.url` property to be added to API responses.

Comment: Thank you so much Kim!! Your effort in helping me has improved the speed time by 50x!